# Двоеточие в полях структуры

Tags: c++, c, структуры

Объясните, пожалуйста, как тут создается структура? Что делает знак двоеточие `:`?

```
/**
 * @brief Bit-field structure of the state of the packet reception
 */
typedef struct{
    uint32_t Length         :16;        /*!< The number of bytes in the packet including header and CRC. */
    uint32_t PF_ERR         :1;         /*!< A sign package PAUSE. */
    uint32_t CF_ERR         :1;         /*!< A sign Management Pack (filtering by MAC and special tags in the field length - 13.14 - octets). */
    uint32_t LF_ERR         :1;         /*!< A sign excess packet length 1518 octets. */
    uint32_t SF_ERR         :1;         /*!< A sign of lack of packet length 64 octets. */
    uint32_t LEN_ERR        :1;         /*!< A sign mismatch between the actual length and the length specified in the length field - 13.14 octets. */
    uint32_t DN_ERR         :1;         /*!< A sign bit of the packet is not a multiple of 8. */
    uint32_t CRC_ERR        :1;         /*!< A sign mismatch packet CRC. */
    uint32_t SMB_ERR        :1;         /*!< A sign of the presence in the packet error nibbles. */
    uint32_t MCA            :1;         /*!< A sign group package (MAC matches HASH). */
    uint32_t BCA            :1;         /*!< A sign of the broadcast packet (MAC = FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF). */
    uint32_t UCA            :1;         /*!< A sign individual package (MAC corresponds to the set). */
}ETH_StatusPacketReceptionBitFileds;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

В названии самой структуры ETH_StatusPacketReception**BitFileds** присутствует словосочетание **BitFileds**. Эта структура задает битовые поля, то есть более компактную форму записи целочисленных членов данных структуры, так как заранее известно, что эти члены данных будут хранить ограниченные значения, и для их представления достаточно выделить несколько битов.

Например, вы могли бы определить эту структуру следующим образом:

```
typedef struct{
    uint32_t Length;        /*!< The number of bytes in the packet including header and CRC. */
    uint32_t PF_ERR;         /*!< A sign package PAUSE. */
    //...
}ETH_StatusPacketReceptionBitFileds;
```

Но в таком случае каждый член данных структуры занимал бы память в 32 бита, или 4 байта. А если известно, например, что член данных структуры `PF_ERR` может принимать только два значения 0 или 1, то будет расточительно хранить эти значения в члене данных, имеющим 32 бита, так как для представления 0 или 1 достаточно всего лишь одного бита. Поэтому структура определяется как структура с битовыми полями с заданным количеством битов. Эти битовые поля упаковываются компилятором в объекты, как указано в объявлении битовых полей структуры, типа 
`uint32_t`. То есть в принципе в одном объекте данного типа может быть упаковано 32 битовых поля размером в 1 бит. Это экономит память, выделяемую под объекты структуры.

Из стандарта C++ (9.6 Bit-fields [class.bit])

> 1 A member-declarator of the form

```
identifieropt attribute-specifier-seqopt: constant-expression
```

> specifies a bit-field; its length is set off from the bit-field name
>   by a colon.,,,
>   **Bit-fields are packed into some addressable allocation unit**.

Comment: Нет, `uint32_t` это не тип в который упаковывается поле, а тип временной переменной в которую *распаковывается* поле при операциях с ним. Я вообще сомневаюсь, что с объектом в который упаковываются поля связан какой-либо тип (по крайней мере тип, доступный в коде)

Comment: @avp Вы можете послать свое сообщение о дефекте стандарта в комитет по стандартизации. На самом деле тип играет роль. Например, на размер структуры, на знаковость, на возможные дополнения в структуре, как будут интерпретироваться биты: как знаковые или беззнаковые.

Comment: А я о чем? Мы всегда указываем **тип поля** и количество его **младших разрядов**, которые пакуются в некий контейнер, а не тип контейнера (полей контейнера) в который упаковано поле. И еще на всякий случай, не получится сделать размер поля больше чем размер его типа.

Answer (score 13):

После двоеточия для члена структуры задается размер этого члена в битах. Т.е. такой член является битовым полем. В основном это используется для упаковки данных и при этом сохранения удобного доступа на изменение и чтения значения.
При этом для битового поля запрещена операция взятия адреса.

Собственно в комментарии к структуре уже содержится ответ:

> ```
> Bit-field structure ...
> ```