# Что значат : в переменной С++ Builder и как реализовать тоже на C#

Tags: c#, c++

Помогите разобраться, что значит

> :

В переменной ниже приведу структуру на С++ Builder:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int nr:8;   //
    unsigned int y:8;    // 1
    unsigned int sm:3;   // 2
    unsigned int d:5;    // 3
    unsigned int m:4;    // 4
    unsigned int r:4;    // 5
} n_def;
```

Что именно значит число после `:`? `nr:8` или `3` или `5` ..... и т.д.? 
И как тоже самое реализовать на C#?

Дело в том что мне нужно прочитать данные из бинарного файла, и как я понял мне для начала нужно прочитать весь блок а затем разбить его на биты ? в C# чтение производиться так:

```
         using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open)))
            {
                // пока не достигнут конец файла
                // считываем каждое значение из файла
                while (reader.PeekChar() > -1)
                {
                    int numb = reader.ReadInt32();
                    uint nr = reader.ReadUInt32(); // переменная которую нужно разбить на биты 
   }
}
```

Я правильно понял ? как правильнее реализовать ? может лучше использовать маршалинг ? Спасибо за ваши ответы

Comment: [По поводу того, что это означает в С++.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/583956/181100)

Comment: Также [подобный вопрос на en SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464/bit-fields-in-c-sharp)

Comment: а оно вот прям-таки надо на шарпе? :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Двоеточие применяется для того, чтобы указать размер переменной в битах. Такая запись работает только внутри структур, где несколько небольших значений из 2-х или 3-х бит могут быть слиты в одну 16, 32 или 64-хбитовую целую переменную.

В вашем примере все переменные поместятся в 32-хбитовое целое число. В действительности это и будет одна целая переменная, а компилятор сгенерирует вам код для доступа к отдельным битам.

На C#, как и в C++ вместо такой записи часто применяют прямую манипуляцию битами.
Например, чтобы выделить три бита, начиная с пятого, вы делаете так:

```
var y = (x >> 4) & 0x07;
```

Сначала вы сдвигаете число на 4 бит вправо, теряя младшие 4 бита. Затем накладываете маску 00000111<sub>2</sub>, стирая старшие 5 бит и оставляя младшие 3. В результате вы получаете три бита: пятый, шестой и седьмой.

Чтобы установить эти биты вы можете сначала стереть их, а затем применить операцию ИЛИ:

```
var y = (y & 0x8F) | (x << 4);
```

Здесь 0x8F это 10001111<sub>2</sub>, а х содержит новое значение для этих 3-х бит.

Впрочем, в C# есть структура [BitVerctor32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32(v=vs.110).aspx), которая поможет работать с отдельными битами или группами бит.

Comment: Кроме BitVector32 в C# можно также использовать [Flags] enum - https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc138362.aspx Конечно, не эквивалент битовым полям, но возможно где-то окажется удобно, в том числе в сочетании с предложенным подходом.